# invalid command name "Agent/LeachAgent"

Tags: tcl, ns2

I try to implement a simple scenario for LEACH protocol but I get this error:

```
 Creating Sensors ... 
    invalid command name "Agent/LeachAgent"
        while executing
    "Agent/LeachAgent create _o2340 "
        invoked from within
    "catch "$className create $o $args" msg"
        invoked from within
    "if [catch "$className create $o $args" msg] {
    if [string match "__FAILED_SHADOW_OBJECT_" $msg] {
    delete $o
    return ""
    }
    global errorInfo
    error "class $..."
        (procedure "new" line 3)
        invoked from within
    "new Agent/LeachAgent"
        ("for" body line 3)
        invoked from within
    "for {set i 1} {$i <= $val(nsn)} {incr i} {

        set agent($i) [new Agent/LeachAgent]
        $ns attach-agent $node_($i) $agent($i)
        $agent($i) set packetSize_..."
        (file "newleach3.tcl" line 187)
```

I use `ubuntu 16.04` and `ns-allinone-2.35` . when I ran my `tcl` file for the first time, i did not get this error.

Comment: How does that class get created?

Comment: @glenn jackman, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: `new` and `create` hint at an OTcl class becoming instantiated. The command name `Agent/LeachAgent` is also the class name. Hence, glenn's right-minded question. Turns out, `Agent/LeachAgent` does not exist. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change your script to use `Agent/RCAgent/LeachAgent` as class name:

```
set agent($i) [new Agent/RCAgent/LeachAgent]
```

From what I can see, there is no `Agent/LeachAgent` in `ns-allinone-2.35`.

Comment: yes , your are right .LEACH protocol is not supported with ns-allinone-2.35 but I added it  and my scenario worked correctly. I got this error recently. I tested your solution but it didn't work.

Comment: well, unless you disclose how you contributed LEACH to ns, no one will be able to help you. Best guess that registering the `TclClass` with the `interp` is broken in some way. Why not stick with an already patched ns 2.35 including LEACH, such as: https://github.com/paultsr/ns-allinone-2.35/tree/7c93412391263673ff459664244bd395930f2ff0/ns-2.35/mannasim/leach?

Comment: The MIT Leach has no definition like `LeachAgent`. (Or similar.) ... Mannasim uses `set agent [new Agent/RCAgent/LeachAgent]`.

Comment: Mannasim is what I am referring to, yes.

Answer (score 0):

I was not successful in writing a correct code for attaching Leach protocol in my scenario, but I found that mannasim has a Mannasim Script Generator (MSG). It is a front-end for `TCL` simulation scripts easy creation.