# invalid command name in tcl script

Tags: tcl, ns2

invalid command name in tcl while running my tcl script for new protocol  in ns2 it shows error as:

```
num_nodes is set 108 invalid command name “Agent/HEBM”
      while executing
“Agent/HEBM set radius_2”
(file  “balance.tcl” line31)
```

please, reply as soon as possible, it will be very helpful to implement my project.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51834497/how-can-i-fix-this-error-in-ns2 by @Ahmed Alfaris, today.

Comment: This Q may help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51595992/7552

Answer (score 0):

It is because tkinter window closed but other processes related to it are still running. To avoid this, put `try` and `except` wherever the error is occurring in your code. To avoid the error, do this whenever the error function is called:

```
import sys
...
try: the_function()
except: sys.exit(1)
```

Fell free to comment in case of more detail requirement or any error if occurred.